# "InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)" when updating package list

Tags: apt

Here is what I see in my terminal:

```
user@user-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                    
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 1,661 B] [Connecting to 192.168.0.90 (192.168.0.90)] [WaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease intoIgn http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I have the required authentication information in /etc/apt/apt.conf file:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@192.168.0.90:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@192.168.0.90:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@192.168.20.0:8080/";
```

I am not able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One way for that is to remove dl.google.com from your software update repositories,

for that, use System Settings -> Software & Update -> Other Software

and uncheck dl.google.com

then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I could not find a way to keep google in circle because I live in Iran & google refuses service to users in Iran.

Comment: Recently I came to know that dl.google.com is being blocked by my proxy, and I cannot unblock it, because my system is part of an instituional network.

Comment: make sure you uncheck both the repositories of dl.google.com

Answer (score 4):

Just follow below 3 easy steps, and it works for me:

Step 1: Edit google-chrome.list repo file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Step 2: Comment the "dl.google.com..." line and save the file:

```
# deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Step 3: Run update again:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try remove some repositorie, be careful with that repositories to you deletes

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.lists.d/***.list

and later

sudo apt-get update -y

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes problem is with your ISP service providers. Your IP might be in blacklist. Please check on https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and type in your IP to see the results. If you see your IP as listed, you can click on details and request for delisting your IP

I had the same problem and without a proper knowledge, I re-installed the OS and had the same issue. I fixed this issue by delisting from blacklist.