# apt-get update broken in jessie main InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: debian, gnupg, apt

I know this looks like a copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487165/inrelease-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nodata-does-the-network-require), however the solutions offered there do not work for me as I have already disabled dl.google.com and am running into further issues.

Here's the terminal output

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg   
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [7,900 B]
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [2,704 B]
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release                     
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources              
Get:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 2016-03-26-2053.48.pdiff [527 B]
Get:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 2016-04-10-2047.32.pdiff [2,817 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Get:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 2016-04-19-2053.08.pdiff [2,111 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 2016-04-23-1455.20.pdiff [378 B]
Get:7 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 2016-05-02-2123.23.pdiff [254 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
100% [InRelease gpgv 20.1 kB] [Waiting for headers]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.debian.org_unstable_dists_jessie-main_InRelease into data anIgn https://packages.debian.org jessie-main InRelease
E: GPG error: https://packages.debian.org jessie-main InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Whereas before I was stuck on 80 something % and, like the original poster on the last question, could see that it was dl.google.com causing it, I have no further leads as to what to try...

Comment: Consider asking on Super User instead, as this is not a question about software development (but general computer usage) and will likely be closed therefor as off topic. The other question also is off topic here, but seems to have been passed through the community filter.

Comment: thank you, will do

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`